# Getting "The server could not be contacted." when trying to access active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying this code:

```
public bool isTravelAdmin(string srvr, string usr, string password)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I'm in isTravelAdmin!");

    PrincipalContext domainctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, srvr);

    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, usr);

    bool isMember = userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(domainctx, IdentityType.Name, "traveladmin");

    if (isMember)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user is INDEED a member of that group");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user is *NOT* member of that group");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to check if a user belongs to a certain group ("traveladmin"), but I'm getting

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException

Any idea why and how to solve? by the way:

```
srvr = "LDAP://192.168.56.101/CN=Users,DC=estagioit,DC=local"
```

PS: I'm using the same srvr on another method and it's working and connecting.

PSS: If this is not the best way to go about this I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case just change your `srvr` to:

```
srvr = "DCESTAGIO"
```

Comment: how would you know that FQDN "DC=estagioit,DC=local" translates to pre-Windows 2000 domain name "DCESTAGIO"? is there a fixed rule to translate such names or was that information included in a comment that is now deleted? like this, it is difficult to replicate this QA in similar situations.

Comment: COULD U EXPLAIN THAT ?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is how the "Principal Context" is written... it should be:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DCESTAGIO");
```

in this case.

If you look at the documentation for the `PrincipalContext` constructors, it should be quite clear:

```
public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name)
```

or

```
public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name, string container)
```

So you basically need:

- your context type (here: `ContextType.Domain`)
- the domain name (try    just the "Netbios" name, e.g. "YOURDOMAIN" -
  or leave NULL for    "default" domain)
- optionally a container (as an LDAP path - a    "distinguished" name,
  full path but without any `LDAP://` prefix)

as seen in [this](http://If%20you%20look%20at%20the%20documentation%20for%20the%20PrincipalContext%20constructors,%20it%20should%20be%20quite%20clear:%20%20public%20PrincipalContext(ContextType%20contextType,%20string%20name)%20or%20%20public%20PrincipalContext(ContextType%20contextType,%20string%20name,%20string%20container)%20So%20you%20basically%20need:%20%20your%20context%20type%20(here:%20ContextType.Domain)%20the%20domain%20name%20(try%20just%20the) answer.

Comment: `this` answer is a blank link

Comment: Where does "DCESTAGIO" come from? It's not given in the question.