# c# How to list all windows users ( especially domain accounts )

Tags: c#, windows

I need to list all windows users in C#

This is my code:

```
var usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( @"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount" );
var users         = usersSearcher.Get();
```

Unfortunately this code didn't return domain accounts, why?

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    string domainName = "";
 
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
 
    if (grp != null)
    {
         foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
            }
 
 
        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: Instead of `.Dispose` use a `using` block

Comment: @Skalpel02 i got error "The server cannot be contacted."

Comment: @MTS I guess there can be problem with Context, please see this issue, I guess there can be an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493506/getting-the-server-could-not-be-contacted-when-trying-to-access-active-direct